# System.out.print not displaying ArrayList<Object>

Tags: java, object, arraylist, system.out

The object "accountData" will not display in the console in the CloseAccount() method. I have tried various variants of the for loop but it just either displays "0." after the header or nothing at all after the header. I just want to be able to print all the elements of the ArrayList (and their element object data) to the user.

```
import java.util.*;
    public class AccountManagement {
        Scanner PETE = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<BankAccount> accountData = new ArrayList<BankAccount>();
        public AccountManagement() {
            do {
                System.out.println("MANAGER (0) OR CUSTOMER (1): ");
                int userSelect = PETE.nextInt();
                if(userSelect == 0) {
                    Manager();
                    break;
                }else if(userSelect == 1){
                    Customer();
                    break;
                }else {
                    System.out.println("Please pick a valid selection");
                }
            }while(true);
            PETE.close();
        }
        private void Manager() {
            do {
                System.out.println("\t0. Open Account\n\t1. Close Account\n");
                int accountOpt = PETE.nextInt();
                if(accountOpt == 0) {
                    OpenAccount();
                }else if(accountOpt == 1) {
                    CloseAccount();
                }else {
                    System.out.println("Please pick a valid selection");
                }
            }while(true);
        }
        private void Customer() {
            do {
                //things
            }while(true);
        }
        private void OpenAccount() {
            do {
                System.out.println("Checking (0) or Savings (1): ");
                int CoS = PETE.nextInt();
                if(CoS == 0) {
                    System.out.println("SSN: ");
                    long SSN = PETE.nextLong();
                    System.out.println("PIN: ");
                    int PIN = PETE.nextInt();
                    Random rand = new Random();
                    int ACCNUM = rand.nextInt(10000);

                    CheckingAccount CA = new CheckingAccount(ACCNUM, PIN, SSN, 0);

                    System.out.println("Would you like to also add a savings account? (0 = Yes, 1 = No)");
                    int sav = PETE.nextInt();
                    if(sav == 0) {
                        ACCNUM = rand.nextInt(10000);
                        SavingsAccount SA = new SavingsAccount(ACCNUM, PIN, SSN, 0);
                        BankAccount BA = new BankAccount(CA, SA);
                        accountData.add(BA);
                    }else if (sav == 1) {
                        break;
                    }else {
                        System.out.println("Please enter a valid selection");
                    }
                }else if(CoS == 1) {
                    System.out.println("SSN: ");
                    long SSN = PETE.nextLong();
                    System.out.println("PIN: ");
                    int PIN = PETE.nextInt();
                    Random rand = new Random();
                    int ACCNUM = rand.nextInt(10000);

                    SavingsAccount SA = new SavingsAccount(ACCNUM, PIN, SSN, 0);

                    System.out.println("Would you like to also add a checking account? (0 = Yes, 1 = No)");
                    int check = PETE.nextInt();
                    if(check == 0) {
                        ACCNUM = rand.nextInt(10000);
                        CheckingAccount CA = new CheckingAccount(ACCNUM, PIN, SSN, 0);
                        BankAccount BA = new BankAccount(CA, SA);
                        accountData.add(BA);
                    }else if (check == 1) {
                        break;
                    }else {
                        System.out.println("Please enter a valid selection");
                    }
                }else {
                    System.out.println("Please pick a valid selection");
                }
            }while(true);
        }
        private void CloseAccount() {
            System.out.println("Which account would you like to close?");
            System.out.println("Selection\tCA ACCTNUM\tSA ACCTNUM");
            for(int x = 0; x < accountData.size(); x++) {
                System.out.println(x+".\t");
                System.out.print(accountData.get(x).CA.getAccountNumber()+"\t"+accountData.get(x).SA.getAccountNumber());
            }
            int selection = PETE.nextInt();
            accountData.remove(selection);
        }
        public ArrayList<BankAccount> getAccounts() {
            return accountData;
        }

    }
```

Comment: `PETE.close();` is not a good idea on a stream you didn't created (ie closing the system input stream)

Comment: What is your input data? COuld u please share your test data as well?

Answer (score 1):

I just tested it on local and it prints for me. Just use `println` instead of `print` to test it.

[image: My local test]

When I changed `print` to `println` I got printed data as below:

[image: Printed data using println instead of print]

Comment: In my code there are certain situations where the BankAccount Object would not get assigned to the ArrayList, so PICNIC. Thank you though!